# Android REST API call with no response from back end for new records

Tags: android, json, rest, heroku, kotlin

I am developing `android app` for course project. My app has back end (`REST API`) which I developed and deployed on `Heroku`. Now I am trying to fetch the data from back end. I used `Retrofit` (`network API`) and `Moshi` (for parsing `JSON` string).

I have successfully got response from the back end with 3 records for the first time (The records were created when I write the `API` in `Ruby on Rails`). Then for testing the app, I sent `POST` for 2 records from `Postman` and I run the app again. This time I got no response. Then I send `DELETE` operation for the last 2 added records and I run the app again, this time I got response for the old records. Then I send another `DELETE` operation from `Postman` for one of old record and send `POST` operation. Then the app displays no response. I deleted the new records, then the app displays the old records.

Generally the `app` is displaying old records only. whenever I send new `POST` operation, I didn't get response. I am surprised by what is happening. Can someone tell me what could be the problem? I have cleared all the `caches` in my phone, restarted the phone, reinstalled the app but still the problem exists.

(I can GET all the data successfully from Postman and Browser)

**`EventApiService.kt`   // where I define Retrofit and Moshi objects**

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://eventnotifierjson2.herokuapp.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()


interface EventApiInterface{
    @GET("events")
    fun getEvents():
            Deferred<List<Event>>
}

object EventApi {

    val retrofitService : EventApiInterface by lazy {
        retrofit.create(EventApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

============================
**ViewModel for EventsListFragment**

```
class EventListViewModel: ViewModel(){

     private val _eventResponses = MutableLiveData<List<Event>>()

    val eventResponses : LiveData<List<Event>>
        get() = _eventResponses


    private val _responseStatus = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val responseStatus : LiveData<String>
        get() = _responseStatus

    private val eventCoroutineJob = Job()

    private val eventCoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(eventCoroutineJob  + Dispatchers.Main)

    init {
        retrieveEventsInBackground()
    }
    private fun retrieveEventsInBackground() {
        eventCoroutineScope.launch {
            // Get the Deferred object for our Retrofit request
            var getPropertiesDeferred = EventApi.retrofitService.getEvents()
            try {
                // this will run on a thread managed by Retrofit
                val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
                _eventResponses.value = listResult
                Log.i("RETROFIT ZEK: ", _eventResponses.value.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _responseStatus.value = e.message
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        eventCoroutineJob.cancel()
    }

}
```

================================

```
class EventListFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding : FragmentEventListBinding
    private val viewModel: EventListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventListViewModel::class.java)
    }
    private lateinit var eventAdapter : EventsRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        binding = FragmentEventListBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        initializeRecyclerView()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initializeRecyclerView(){
        binding.eventsRecyclerView.apply {
             layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@EventListFragment.context)
            val cardDecoration = CardViewDecoration(30)
            addItemDecoration(cardDecoration)
            eventAdapter = EventsRecyclerAdapter()
            adapter = eventAdapter
        }
    }
```

## }

**BindingAdapters for recycler view and image to be displayed**

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView,  data: List<Event>?){
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as EventsRecyclerAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data)
}

@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?) {
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_gerald_g_boy_face_cartoon)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_gerald_g_boy_face_cartoon))
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

==========================
**Data Class for Event objects in retrieved from JSON array**

```
data class Event(val id: Int,
                 val title: String,
                 val description: String,
                 val country: String,
                 val city:  String,
                 @Json(name = "event_location") val eventLocation : String,
                 @Json(name = "event_date") val eventDate : String,
                 @Json(name = "event_time") val eventTime: String,
                 @Json(name = "event_status") val eventStatus: String,
                 @Json(name = "user_id") val userId: Int,
                 @Json(name = "created_at") val createdAt: String,
                 @Json(name = "updated_at") val updatedAt: String,
                 val eventimage : EventImage)
data class EventImage(
   val url: String
```

## )

**fragment_event_list.xml** // The view where I inflate the ViewHolder to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <data>
      <variable
          name="viewModel"
          type="com.mobapproject.eventsroom.modelviews.EventListViewModel" />
   </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.EventListFragment">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:listData="@{viewModel.eventResponses}"
       android:id="@+id/eventsRecyclerView"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

============================
**events_list_layout.xml** // layout for the ViewHolder

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:imageUrl="@{eventsData.eventimage.url}"
            android:id="@+id/event_image"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/event_image"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/container1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/event_title"
                android:text="@{eventsData.title}"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="19sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/event_location"
                android:text="@{eventsData.eventLocation}"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

=============================
**JSON response looks the following**

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Dummy title",
"description": "Dummy Description",
"country": "Italy",
"city": "Rome",
"event_location": "Rome",
"event_date": "2019-11-26",
"event_time": "2000-01-01T21:28:16.000Z",
"event_status": "open",
"user_id": 1,
"created_at": "2019-11-25T01:51:36.075Z",
"updated_at": "2019-11-25T01:51:36.075Z",
"eventimage": {
      "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/zakstorage/....."
        }
}
```

Comment: show us the code or error logs so that it'll be easy for us to find out what went wrong.

Comment: @Jayanth

There is no error, because the app runs but blank fragment. I have edited the post and added the code that I wrote so far. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, I had commited a fault. I have been sending incorrect param to POST operation and Moshi could't parse the NULL value